# Define nested derived table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am converting SQL query into linq ef 6.0. I have a problem when convert nest derived table into linq query. Following is SQL query and Linq expression where i stuck

```
Select * FROM    orders ords WITH ( NOLOCK )  
                INNER JOIN orders_list ol WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON ords.order_id = ol.order_id      

                                                             --AND ol.order_list_id = @order_list_id      
                INNER JOIN product WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON product.id = ol.product_id  
                INNER JOIN OrderContact ca WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON ca.id= ords.OrdercontactRecipientId  --and ca.is_primary_address = 1      
                INNER JOIN OrderContact ca1 WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON ca1.id=ords.OrderContactCustomerID--and ca.is_primary_address = 1     


                LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  oslTemp.order_list_id ,  
                                    status_id  
                            FROM    Ticket_status_log  
                                    INNER JOIN ( SELECT osl.order_list_id ,  
                                                        MAX(log_id) AS log_id  
                                                 FROM   Ticket_status_log osl  
                                                        INNER JOIN orders_list  
                                                        WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON orders_list.order_list_id = osl.order_list_id  
                                                 WHERE  osl.is_deleted = 0  
                                                        AND osl.status_id > 0  
                                                        AND osl.status_id < 3  
                                                 GROUP BY osl.order_list_id  
                                               ) AS oslTemp ON oslTemp.log_id = Ticket_status_log.log_id  
                          ) status_log ON ol.order_list_id = status_log.order_list_id  
        WHERE   ords.is_deleted = 0
```

Following is linq expression

```
var query = (from ords in con.ordersDB
                             join ol in con.Orders_ListDB on ords.order_id equals ol.order_id
                             join product in con.ProductDB on ol.product_id equals product.ID
                             join ca in con.OrderContactDB on ords.OrderContactRecipientID equals ca.ID
                             join ca1 in con.OrderContactDB on ords.OrderContactCustomerID equals ca1.ID

                             join tktlog in con.ticket_status_logDB 
                             )
```

I have stuck when there is derived nest table join. How to handle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figure it out by myself. I am posting the answer so that any other will get the solution

```
    var innerQuery2 = (from tktlog in con.ticket_status_logDB
                                       join ordlist in con.Orders_ListDB on tktlog.order_list_id equals ordlist.order_list_id
                                       where tktlog.is_deleted == false && tktlog.status_id > 0 && tktlog.status_id < 3
                                       group tktlog by tktlog.order_list_id into grouped
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           order_list_id = grouped.Key,
                                           log_id = grouped.Select(x => x.log_id).Max()
                                       });
                    var innerQuery1 = (from tktlog in con.ticket_status_logDB
                                       join osltemp in innerQuery2 on tktlog.log_id equals osltemp.log_id
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           osltemp.order_list_id,
                                           tktlog.status_id
                                       });
                    var query = (from ords in con.ordersDB
                                 join ol in con.Orders_ListDB on ords.order_id equals ol.order_id
                                 join product in con.ProductDB on ol.product_id equals product.ID
                                 join ca in con.OrderContactDB on ords.OrderContactRecipientID equals ca.ID
                                 join ca1 in con.OrderContactDB on ords.OrderContactCustomerID equals ca1.ID
                                 join cityml in con.CityMLDB on ca.CityMLID equals cityml.ID into leftcityml
                                 from citymlresult in leftcityml.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 join state in con.StateDB on ca.StateID equals state.ID into leftstate
                                 from stateresult in leftstate.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 join area in con.AreaMLDB on ca.AreaMLID equals area.ID into leftarea
                                 from arearesult in leftarea.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 join statuslog in innerQuery1 on ol.order_list_id equals statuslog.order_list_id into leftquery1
                                 from status_log in leftquery1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 where ords.is_deleted == false && ords.is_voided == false && ords.type_id == 2
                                 && (ol.item_number ?? 0) > 0 &&
                                 (
                                    (
                                        (ol.parent_id == parintid || ol.parent_id == orderListId || ol.order_list_id == orderListId)
                                        && (ol.SubType ?? 0) == 4
                                    )
                                        || (ol.order_list_id == orderListId)
                                 )
                                 orderby arearesult.Name ?? ca.AreaOther
select new {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use let clause to solve this problem  [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause).

Write you subquery in let and then join the  let variable with other table variables